# Stolz–Cesàro theorem proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $\lim a_n = + \infty$ and $\lim b_n  = +\infty$, and $b_n$ is strictly increasing.

Suppose also that $\lim \frac{a_{n+1} - a_n}{b_{n+1} - b_n} = L$.

This implies that: $(L - \epsilon)(b_{n+1} - b_n) < a_{n+1} - a_n < (L+\epsilon).(b_{n+1} - b_n)$ for all $n > N(\epsilon)$ where $N(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$.

How do I show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n > N$,   $L - \epsilon < \frac{a_{n} - a_N}{b_{n} - b_N} < L + \epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to add the inequality you have form $n=N$ to $n=m$. This gives you $(L-\epsilon)(b_{m+1}-b_N) <a_{m+1}-a_N<(L+\epsilon)(b_{m+1}-b_N)$. Now change $m$ to $n-1$ and divide both sides by $b_{n}-b_N$.

Comment: So the above implies $\lim \frac{a_n - a_N}{b_n - b_N} = \frac{\lim a_n - a_N}{\lim b_n - b_N} =  L$, since $\lim b_n - b_{N} \neq 0$. How to get from here to $\lim \frac{a_n}{b_n} = L$?

Comment: Divide all the terms in numerator and denominator by $b_n$ and use the fact that $b_n \to \infty$.